# How do I properly mix C# code within JavaScript, using Razor view engine. I wish to include or omit Javascript based on a value in ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I only want this JavaScript to be included in the response to the browser
if ViewBag.L1Cat does not equal null. At the moment I am getting the error:
**cannot perform run time binding on a null reference.** And the debugger
does not want to stop inside the if statement for some reason. ViewBag was
populated with respective keys\value pairs in the action method that returns
the view.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 @{
    if(ViewBag.L1Cat != null)
    {
       <text>              
          var FirstLevel = 
                    $('#MenuContainer')
                       .find('.FirstLevel')
                       .attr('@(ViewBag.RootCat.ToString());');
       </text>        
     }
   }    
 </script>
```

Comment: Your error is a C# compile error? Is the html rendered out correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it absolutely necessary to omit the code?

You might find it cleaner to take this approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var doStuff = @(ViewBag.L1Cat != null ? "true" : "false");
if (doStuff)
{
var FirstLevel = $('#MenuContainer').find('.FirstLevel').attr('@(ViewBag.RootCat.ToString())');
}
</script>
```

Alternatively

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if(ViewBag.L1Cat != null)
{
 <text>              
  var FirstLevel = $('#MenuContainer').find('.FirstLevel').attr('@(ViewBag.RootCat.ToString())');
 </text>        
}
</script>
```

Comment: Preferable, why send unnecessary data that won't be used in the response.

Comment: Because it messes up your code. Clean code > random optimizations